# what is the best way to full text search in a large Array of String in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, lucene, full-text-search

i have an large Array of String, say its length is about 30000, and also those string are fairly long (about 10 line of text). now my Question is what is best way to search in this array? someone told me to use FTS3, is it possible to search in arrays?
or apache lucene?

i want and an advanced search.

Comment: It might be worth adding the <java> tag to this as it's not exclusive to Android

Comment: You may not have enough heap space for 30,000 10-line strings.

Comment: `Question is what is best way to search in this array?` Question is why not use database(sqlite) instead

Comment: i think you are right, i completely forgot heap Space.

Comment: in my app i need to search as fast as possible in this array or SQLite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should hold 30.000 string of +/- 10 lines in memory. As CommonsWare told before this would put the heap under a lot of (unnecessary) preassure.

A few possabilities come to mind to store the strings and make them accessable for string comparison. You could store the string in a database and use full text search options. But you could also save tham in a file (for example a JSON file) and use a buffered stream in order to compare the strings.

Comment: how faster can i have access to heap than sqlite database?

Comment: Maybe this advice to not hold 30,000 small text documents in an array as being too large for memory might have been accurate in 2014. . . but I don't think it was even then. Systems commonly had 2 to 16G of RAM in 2014, IIRC. 30,000 strings of say, average length of 80 chars per line * 10 lines average document size, would be about 24MB. Which is NOTHING for a system with 8G of RAM.

There might be other good reasons not to do it, like persistence. If that data is at all being persisted, might be better to use some sort of DB.